# Return all coordinates of ROC curve and save into a list

Tags: r, list, roc, coords

I would like to save all coordinates of a ROC curve into a list so that I can later on plot multiple ROC curves.

How do I specify my x value to return all coordinates?

```
roc_train <- roc(target~prob, data=ordered_test, col="#1c61b6")
coord_list <- list()
coord_list[1] <- coords(roc_train)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using the `pROC` package. The `x` argument can be set to `"all"` as in

```
coord_list[[1]] <- coords(roc_train, x = "all")
```

This will return all coordinates of the ROC curve.